# does swagger supports generation of swagger file for net4.7.x framework version?

Tags: .net, swagger, swagger-codegen

I have used swagger cli to generate the dotnet core projects running on 3.x and 6.x using `dotnet swagger tofile [options] [startupassembly] [swaggerdoc]` but i'm not able to use the same tool for the project that is running on .net4.7.x.

Getting below error when running the above command

**The specified deps.json does not exist**

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to manually add the respective nuget packages manually.  According to their nuget pages [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/swashbuckle.aspnetcore.swaggerui/#supportedframeworks-body-tab) and [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/swashbuckle.aspnetcore.swaggergen/#supportedframeworks-body-tab), they indirectly support .Net Framework v4.7 by supporting .Net Standard 2.0.

To actually make sure it works, I guess just go for it.